# Differing from lists/tuples from strings during iteration

Tags: python

Is a common pattern to write functions that accept an argument, and if the argument is a scalar like a number or a string, you apply some operation on it, and if the argument is a iterable, you apply the same operation on each element of this iterable

The problem is that string is iterable, so I can't rely on *Ask for forgiveness not for permission* for achieving this, because `iter('hello world')` will not raise TypeError.

For example

```py
def apply_(func, val):
    try:
        for v in iter(val):
            print(func(v), end=' ')
        print()
    except TypeError:
        print(func(val))


apply_(lambda x: x+1, 1) # 2 ...  Ok
apply_(lambda x: x*2, range(3)) # 0 2 4 ... Ok
apply_(str.upper, ['hello', 'world']) # HELLO WORLD ... Okay
apply_(str.upper, 'hello world') # H E L L O   W O R L D, ... oops
```

I can *ask for persmission*. But this will work only for subtypes of string.

```py
def apply_safe(func, val):
    if issubclass(type(val), str):
        print(func(val))
        return

    try:
        for v in iter(val):
            print(func(v), end=' ')
        print()
    except TypeError:
        print(func(val))
```

Another option is to add this logic to the type, which seems to be the right way of doing this since being iterable is undesired (for this case) behavior of string. But this is error prone for the caller, soon or later it will forget to call it with `NonIterableString` or any other class.

```py
class NonIterableString(str):
    def __iter__(self):
        raise TypeError()

apply(str.upper, NonIterableString('hello world')) # HELLO WORLD
```

The last solution I found is this which fix my problem but may not work for existing code is this

```py
def apply_multi(func, *vals):
    for v in vals:
        print(func(v), end=' ')
    print()
```

This seems to be the more idiomatic one. It always works, is small and elegant, but because it doesn't face the problem, it smartly circumvent it. Here the problem is that I need to write a function like this for each case of this, which it doesn't seems to be a bad idea, but is still verbose...

Finally here is the complete example

```py
def apply_(func, val):
    try:
        for v in iter(val):
            print(func(v), end=' ')
        print()
    except TypeError:
        print(func(val))

def apply_safe(func, val):
    if (issubclass(type(val), str)):
        print(func(val))
        return

    try:
        for v in iter(val):
            print(func(v), end=' ')
        print()
    except TypeError:
        print(func(val))

def apply_multi(func, *vals):
    for v in vals:
        print(func(v), end=' ')
    print()

class NonIterableString(str):
    def __iter__(self):
        raise TypeError()

apply_(lambda x: x+1, 1) # 2 => ok
apply_(lambda x: x*2, range(3)) # 0 2 4 => ok
apply_(str.upper, ['hello', 'world']) # HELLO WORLD => ok
apply_(str.upper, 'hello world') # H E L L O   W O R L D => oops
apply_(str.upper, NonIterableString('hello world')) # HELLO WORLD => ok
apply_safe(str.upper, 'Hello world') # HELLO WORLD =>j
apply_multi(str.upper, 'hello world') # HELLO WORLD => ok
```

Finally my question is, is there any *AFFNFP* way of dealing strings in python like a scalar type instead of an iterable one?

Comment: `apply_multi` is the best option.  Why guess?  The caller knows whether they have a one-thing or a many-things.

Comment: Maybe `if not isinstance(...)` ?

Comment: @NedBatchelder not aways. He may be composing and trying to keep the same behavior.

Comment: I know this is very *naive*, but you can call `apply_(str.upper, ("hello world",))`

Comment: In this case I was trying to mimetize the Rails behavior. If you do model.find(1) it returns the id with one, if you do `model.find([1,2,3])` it returns the models 1, 2 and 3, so the central idea is not burdening the caller. I want to deal with scalar/multivar in this layer. The `*args` was the best trick I could found. In fact I think that iterable strings by default are evil

Comment: If you want to distinguish a limited number of types from each other and you are able to reduce arguments to a single one, for example using a class ` __init__` to store the func to use, maybe `functools.singledispatch` solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good solution is would be something like this:

```py
defaults = {
    str : False
}

def apply_(func, val, isiter: bool=None):    
    if isiter is None:
        isiter = defaults[type(val)] if type(val) in defaults else True

    if isiter:    
        try:
            for i in iter(val):
                print(func(i), end=' ')
            print()
        except TypeError:
            print(func(val))
    else:
        print(func(val))
```

This approach lets you decide (only when the value is an iterable) if you want to treat the value as iterable or not. Potentially if you want this behavior with string type maybe some day you would apply a function to a list, but only to the list it self and not apply the function to each value.

Here `defaults` represents if an iterable type should be treated as iterable by default, in this case `str` should't be treated as iterable by default.

You has also a param to override this "default" behavior if you want (But only if it makes sense). For example:

```py
apply_(lambda x: x+1, 1) # 2 ...  Ok
apply_(lambda x: x*2, range(3)) # 0 2 4 ... Ok
apply_(str.upper, ['hello', 'world']) # HELLO WORLD ... Okay
```

Til here all is the same, all running as expected. Then lets see:

```py
apply_(str.upper, 'hello world') # HELLO WORLD ... Okay
apply_(str.upper, 'hello world', isiter=True) # H E L L O   W O R L D ... okay
```

As you can see `hello world` at first is treated as a value, just as we define in `defaults` and if we set `isiter=True` then is treated as you setted.

Lets see another example:

```py
apply_(lambda x: 2*x, ['hello', 'world']) # hellohello worldworld ... Okay
apply_(lambda x: 2*x, ['hello', 'world'],  isiter=False) # ['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world'] ... Okay
```

As you can see in the first case the list is treated as an iterable and if we set `isiter=False` the function its applied to the list itself.

Finally lets see if we try to treat a non iterable type as iterable:

```py
apply_(lambda x: x+1, 1, isiter=True) # 2 ...  Ok
```

In this case the `try: except:` handles the error.

The dictionary is very handy because setting defaults behaviors will safe you to have to use `isiter` most of the times.

Comment: But why would you cram two functions into one, with that `isiter: bool=None`, instead of just making two separate functions?

Comment: if you want to apply the function `apply_` to many items in a list of items (where you have iterable and not iterable items) then you don't have to ask every time if the item is iterable or not just to know what function to call. With this you only have to do `apply_(function, item)` and `apply_` will take care how to treat `item`.

Comment: The whole question is about how to separate strings from other iterables, if I let this to the user, well, some day latter I would be user, here, asking the same question.

Comment: @geckos I see, so... you want to accomplish this without checking `type(val) is str` because of  `AFFNFP`? Is that what you mean? Because I assume you know how to solve this using `type(val)`. At the end this is the same, just that you offer the user another option besides the default behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for an AFFNFP way of do it, mainly because handling and exception would lead more bullet proof code. Today, revisiting this question, I'm not sure if there is an exception for this case and this is the point I missed.

Comment: Rails has this nice feature, you may have services working expecting one `id`, and just delegating it to models, that delegate to ActiveRecord, then I needed a list of ids and it just worked. I was amazed, tried to reproduce the same with python in a more generic way, but in that case I was narrowed to list of ints. It looked so generic at that time, but now, it just handle list of numbers and numbers are scalar by nature, while strings aren't. I appreciate you taking time to diving on this :)